# Why don't I need device drivers for a UART to communicate with a Linux box but need device drivers if USB is to be used for communication?

Tags: usb, embedded, uart, linux

I have a Linux box.  I want to troubleshoot certain things and I was told that I need to custom solder pins to communicate using UART as perhaps it doesnt have device drivers to communicate using a USB port which is only there for charging and missing drivers to use TTL.

Why don't I need device drivers to communicate with Linux using UART but need to add drivers if I have to use the USB port?

This is incontext to this [blog](https://zcrc.me/OpenDingux.html) where author mentions:

> **Loading the code**
> Point 1). is easy; by powering ON the RetroMini while pressing B, the CPU will switch into a special mode where it will listen for commands on the USB bus. By sending specially crafted commands, it is possible to load custom code to the RetroMini

and then

> **Debugging the code via UART**
> The simplest way to debug your code is to just make it print stuff to the output console. Print register contents, print “success” if your check worked, print “oh noes” if it failed… If your program outputs text to the console, the whole process of writing a program becomes much easier.

Despite the fact that USB port is present, then why the need to solder extra wires to use UART protocol?

[image]

Comment: Your recommendation is a bit unclear, and there's some missing context. What chip is physically connected to the USB D+/D- pins in your "thing" that you want to troubleshoot? What device class does it expose? Do you know its VID and PID?

Comment: If you are using a USB plug but communicating with UART, you are using a virtual COM port so the USB drivers may be preinstalled. Look up USB-UART bridge. One company is FTDI,

Comment: If you put something on USB bus, then you'll need a device driver for that specific chip that is connected on USB bus. It's a task of this driver to mount additional TTY device.

Comment: Linux includes not only drivers for many local-bus UARTs, but also for most known USB-UARTs and some other USB devices.  Without fully specific details of exactly what you are trying to do, your question is unanswerable.  And unless the device is a development tool or something you are building (in which case you'd need to provide a lot more information) it is also an off topic "product usage question"

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have updated the question, could you please help open it

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I have updated the question to provide more details, what I am concerned that despite the fact that USB port is present, why did the author went to trouble for finding Rx/Tx and sodering additional chip for USB/UART communication. The device above runs linux.

Comment: @nanofarad the device is ingenic JZ4780, I have modified the question to include more details / concerns, From what I understand perhaps the vendor did not expose usb bus to usb and perhaps usb was only for charging the device, so the author had to go to additional trouble to find Rx/Ry in the board as shown in the picture. Could this be the valid reason?

Comment: The question is still unanswerable and off topic.  You need to consult the documentation of this product.

Comment: You didn't actually specify what I asked. The image shows the USB lines going to vias, and I cannot trace them any further -- it depends on where the data lines actually get routed to. Beyond that, it's a question for the product docs as Chris Stratton suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does need drivers - but you are using a standard protocol (USB CDC), so Linux already has the drivers built-in. The USB/UART chip knows how to speak the USB CDC protocol, and so does Linux.

If you have your own chip that speaks USB (but not CDC) then you will need to give Linux a driver so it knows how to speak the chip's protocol.

You could also use a standard USB protocol - like CDC or [MSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_mass_storage_device_class) or [any other standard device class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Device_classes) that your computer has a driver for. Then, your computer can use that driver.

Comment: so what I understand that perhaps the vendor of the device (see updated question) did not expose usb port to USB/CDC protocol? the author mentioned that he is using usb bus to load commands, perhaps usb bus might not be connected to usb port? what confuses me as to why the author went to soo much trouble trying to identify the Rx/Tx for UART communication to hack the device instead of simply listening over usb port..

Comment: @JhonnyS if you need a driver, it's not the CDC protocol